# HDMI connection problem -- Dell Inspiron 3531 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, hdmi, inspiron, xrandr

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity Desktop) on a Dell Inspiron 3531 laptop.

I tried connecting to an external monitor from my laptop's HDMI port. My laptop cannot connect. I ran xrandr. The xrandr says HDMI is disconnected. But strangely it says VGA is connected. This cannot be because my laptop has no VGA port. It only has HDMI.

I disconnected the HDMI cable from the HDMI port. Xrandr continue to indicate VGA is connected. So, I rebooted.

Even after rebooting, with no cable connection of any kind, then running xrandr, I continue to get a VGA is connected message.

What can I correct this?

Comment: what is the output of `xrand -q` ? Edit your question and insert it

Comment: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1366 x 768
default connected primary 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768       76.0*

Comment: Please insert the output in  the question in order to get help from others your question must be full understood with all your experminets to indicate the  problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new mode with a new resolution...
You can do it and apply the new resolution using the command:

```
xrandr --addmode <connection_type> 1200x1000_60.00
```

Where `<connection_type>` is usually VGA1, DP1 or HDMI1.

Comment: After adding new mode and issuing this command:

xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1368x768_60.00

I got :

xrandr: cannot find crtc for output HDMI1

Comment: what is the output of this command?

Comment: After adding new mode and issuing this command: 

xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1368x768_60.00 

I got : 

xrandr: cannot find crtc for output HDMI1

Comment: This occurs becaues you have another screen already active,You can resolve this issue by simply turning off the screen using,

`xrandr --output VGA --off  `  i suppose it's VGA based to your question

Comment: I issued 'xrandr --output VGA1 --off' and ran xrandr again and VGA1 remains connected.

Comment: again im asking you insert the result of the command `xrandr -q` in your question

Answer (score 0):

I guess VGA1 is your laptop screen. To use the HDMI output you usually have to press a function key on the laptop keyboard. It should have an icon of a monitor on it. Connect the HDMI to a monitor then use the function key to toggle between VGA, HDMI and BOTH.

Comment: I guess, you're right. I pressed f1 key and my laptop screen narrows in width. And pressing f1 again it goes back to full width screen.  Perhaps, the problem is with my HDMI port. I bought this laptop on Sale and this may be one of the low-end models from Dell.

Comment: Im using Mint at the moment, although i do use Ubuntu a lot on another PC. Have a look in the system settings, display section. Can you see that you have 2 monitors connected ? Are they both enabled ?